# SQL to count distinct values belonging to another column

Tags: sql, mysql, laravel, group-by, distinct

Best asked with an example.

I have a table:

| id | owner | activity | error |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | q | 1 |
| 2 | A | q | 1 |
| 3 | A | w | 0 |
| 4 | A | e | 0 |
| 5 | A | r | 0 |
| 6 | B | t | 1 |
| 7 | B | y | 1 |
| 8 | B | u | 0 |
| 9 | B | i | 0 |
| 10 | C | o | 1 |
| 11 | C | p | 1 |
| 12 | C | s | 1 |
| 13 | C | f | 0 |
| 14 | D | g | 1 |
| 15 | D | h | 1 |
| 16 | D | j | 1 |
| 17 | D | k | 1 |

And I'd like, for each owner, to get a count of the activities that had an error.

Things to note. I'm not looking for a count of errors, for example row 2 should be ignored as it's for the same activity.

Essentially the result should look like:

| owner | errors_per_activity |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 3 |
| D | 4 |

Obviously the first step is to use a where to get only rows with errors, then i've used various group bys and distinct selectors, but just can't quite get what i need.

Latest attempt is:

```
select `owner`, count(*) as total
from `analytics`
where `error` = 1
group by `owner `
order by `total` desc
```

But this just gives me a count of the number of errors encountered by each owner.

Any help greatly appreciated, if you can do it using Laravel's query builder style then extra bonus points!

Thanks!

Comment: Well this is annoying, tables look to be perfectly formatted in the editor view, but don't show correctly in this view... any help on that would also be useful!

Comment: Add an empty row before the table. (Strange, I know.)

Comment: Simply `count(distinct activity)`?

Comment: And if you want to include owners with no activities with errors you can `count(distinct if(error = 1, activity, null))` and drop your `WHERE` clause.